# Multithread server program in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to write a multithread program in Java where a server listens for connections from clients and spawns a thread to acommodate each client. I have:

```
while(true)
    {
        Socket s = server.accept();    
        ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s);
        Thread t = new Thread(ch);
        t.start();  
    }
```

My question is: whenever it accepts a connection in

```
Socket s = server.accept();
```

and starts executing the following lines of code to create the thread etc., what happens to a request for connection from a client during that time. Is it queued somehow and it will get served in the next loop of `while(true)` or will it be rejected?

thanks,
Nikos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `accept()` returns the TCP handshake is complete and you have a connected client socket (`s` in your code). Until the next call to `accept()` the OS queues pending connection requests.

You might want to check out some tutorial like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a tiny http server](https://github.com/candybon/tinyserver) in Java, which you can find on github. That might be a good example for you to take a look at real-world usage of Sockets and multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered already: yes it is queued and no it is not rejected.

I think that anyone reading this question should first know that when you instantiate a socket:

```
server = new ServerSocket(mPort, mNusers);
```

Java is already implementing a [network socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) ; which has clearly defined behavior. The connection will be rejected however after reaching the limit set.

**Also**, the code posted in the question accepts multiple connections **but looses the refference** for the previous. This may be a "duh" but just in case someone is copy-pasting , you should do something to store all the created sockets or handlers. Perhaps:

```
ClientHandler[] ch = new ClientHandler[mNusers];
int chIndex = 0;
while(true)
    {
        Socket s = server.accept();    
        ch[chIndex] = new ClientHandler(s);
        Thread t = new Thread(ch);
        t.start(); 
        chIndex++;
    }
```

An array may not be the best option but I want to point out that with sockets you should know what's the limit of connections you will allocate

Answer (score 0):

ugh :)

there is a so called SYN-queue, which takes up to the requested amount of not yet established connections (there is a per call and a system-wide limit - not sure if its even user limited).

when "listening" on a ServerSocket, you specify that by - one of the answers says "Nusers" but it is - the size of the "backlog" the socket should keep. in this backlog the pending connections are stored and if it is filled up, all other (should) get a ConnectionRefused.

So

a) increase that when you are to slowly accepting (server.accept())
    connections

b) accept the connections faster by

b.1)  using a ThreadPool (be happy moving the problem to context-switches of the os)

b.2)  use NIO and with that the ability to handle socket-states
    within single threads/CPUs (as long as the internal data throughput is better than the one in the network, this is the more performant option)

have fun